# Can't use \begin{lstlisting} in new environment

Tags: listings, environments

If I include this in my document:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
testing
\end{lstlisting}
```

It compiles and renders as expected. However, if I try to extract that into a new environment thusly:

```
\newenvironment{codeblock}{\begin{lstlisting}}{\end{lstlisting}}
```

And then use it like this:

```
\begin{codeblock}
testing
\end{codeblock}
```

I can no longer compile:

```
! Emergency stop
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

The full log is [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/kentcb/d7853f5f7972a63732c60a6eb50a0326).

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Is the missing backslash `\` in your `codeblock` environment a typo here in the site or is it missing in your document? (`{end{lstlisting}}`)

Comment: `listings` defines it's own newenvironment command: `\lstnewenvironment{name}{starting code}{endind code}`. In this case: `\lstnewenvironment{codeblock}{}{}`.

Comment: This restriction is common with all "verbatim" commands that disable normal tex syntax, they can not be directly nested in another command,